# Oauh with Stackoverflow : error code is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, stack-overflow

I want use oauth with stackexchange with my rails app. I use oauth gem. I take data from my home page app on : https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view/XXX

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :stackexchange, 'Client_Id', 'client_secret', public_key: 'key', site: 'stackoverflow', provider_ignores_state: true
end
```

I use the route `/auth/stackexchange/callback` but I have an error :

```
OAuth2::Error 
: {"error":{"type":"0","message":"code is invalid"}}
```

What code are talking about? How debug?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using the Explicit flow? [Stackexchange auth documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). The error message is pretty clear your code (in this case authorization code) which is used to exchange to Access Token is invalid.
From stackexchange auth documentation see The explicit OAuth 2.0 flow points 3. and 4.